# HTTP ERROR 500 when loading com_cache

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, cache, configuration

Recently, my joomla's website has been showing 500 server error every time I open the cache manager as described below:

[image]

In Browser's Console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Since the website is hosted on Ubuntu, when I check the number of files in the cache directory, it shows there are over 600 thousands files.

```
$ find /var/www/html/cache/ -type f -print | wc -l
659798
```

Though I can remove any folder within the cache directory using `$ rm -r com_example` but I believe this is not the correct approach.

Has anyone experienced the same issue, then please suggest me a proper approach to solve the issue or any necessary tuning in terms of better performance and stability for my joomla website.

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely a php error. Please enable Joomla! Maximum error reporting and see if you see the error. This will provide you with good insight into the cause.

It could be down to max execution time or php memory.

Many thanks
Tony

Comment: Also, check your `error_log` file in the root directory.